# invalid ALTER TABLE option after changing a value to not null

Tags: sql

```
create table agenda
(
    id         number(3),
    first_name varchar(20),
    last_name  varchar2(20),
    phone_nr   char(14)
);

alter table agenda 
    alter column phone_nr char(14) not null;
```

After I tried to change the `phone_nr` variable to not null, I get an error

> Invalid ALTER TABLE option

I'm a beginner at SQL and I don't really understand where the problem is.

Comment: How about `modify column` instead of alter column.

Comment: Please tag your question with the specific database that you're using. [Why should I “tag my RDBMS”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: Each specific database platform supports its own syntax - your code is error free in DB2, so which platform are you using??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't use an `alter column` clause to change a column's nullability, but you could use a `modify column` clause instead:

```sql
alter table agenda modify column phone_nr char(14) not null;
-- Here -----------^
```

Comment: `alter table agenda alter column phone_nr set not null;` is valid ANSI SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that all the `phone_nr` values are set to something that isn't null? You can only `alter` it to be `not null` if all values are something that is not null, otherwise it would contradict itself because its value would be `null` even though the table says it cannot be `null`. You can try this:

```
UPDATE agenda SET phone_nr = '0-000-000-0000' WHERE phone IS NULL;
```

Now, since all `phone_nr` values that were null are set to a value that is not null you can `alter` it to be `NOT NULL` in the table.

Comment: Do you think the presence of a NULL value would result in a `invalid ALTER TABLE option` error message?

Comment: If one of the values of `phone_nr` is null, then wouldn't it make it impossible to `alter` it to `not null` because it shouldn't be able to be null, yet is null? It cannot be not null but be null at the same time.

Comment: Note that fake values instead of NULL tend to cause problems sooner or later.